# Using tabs with multiple lines of text in two columns (InDesign)

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm hoping someone can help with a tabs issue I'm facing in InDesign. I attached a screenshot below. For a resume design, I currently have the left and right information in separate text boxes. However, I am trying to figure out how to create this same design using tabs (as the two text boxes make it difficult to edit and line everything up). I know how to use tabs to create a single line on one side and paragraph text on the other side, however, I cannot figure out how to use tabs when I have multiple lines of text on BOTH sides.

[image]

I've been trying to figure this out for days and am completely stuck, so I'd very much appreciate if anyone has any advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple different ways I can think to do this. Others may have better suggestions.

For me, I'd use the ***first method*** below with anchored text frames.

---

## First

.... merely using *[anchored text frames](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/anchored-objects.html#:%7E:text=When%20you%20place%20the%20object,object%20and%20change%20these%20attributes.)*

Make each "Name of workplace" item a separate text frame. Align the separate frames with each Job Title accordingly. Then you can **anchor** those text frames immediately after/before each "Job Title". As the "Job Title" moves up/down a page, the anchored frame will move right along with it.

[image]

---

## Second

... using tabs within a single text frame.

3 Paragraph Styles - Job title line, line immediately after the job title, and the rest of the job text.

Add a tab after the Job title and the line below it. Then assign a *different* paragraph style with a right indent to the rest of the "Job" text.
This **can** make editing the first line of the job info a bit more cumbersome. But it will still work.

[image]

---

## Third

... a *forced frame jump*.

This would require a different text frame for each job and columns would need to be *equal widths* (which is often *not* the desired layout.)

Add the "Name of Workplace" info in a separate paragraph after the "Job" info. *Before* the "name" line and hold the <kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd> key down and then hit the <kbd>Return</kbd> key. 
<sub>(If your keyboard has an <kbd>Enter</kbd> key you can merely tap that instead - it does the same thing as Ctrl-Return)</sub>

This will force everything after the forced frame job to move to the other column...

[image]

As stated above, this would require a different text frame for *each* job and both columns *must* be the *same* width.

---

For me, the easiest, fastest, most trouble-free, method to edit is the **first** method.

Comment: And the fourth option (possibly the easiest to edit, though page jumps may be an issue) would be to just use a table.

Comment: For me, a table is far more cumbersome than merely anchored frames. But to each his or her own `:)`